# Improve This 404 Checker PHP Script?

Tags: php

It's main purpose is to check URLS. You have to create a 404.txt and sites.txt, put the URLS you want in sites.txt and run the script below called grab.php, any urls which are 404 in sites.txt will go in 404.txt. Remember this has to be in same folder, 404.txt,sites.txt and grab.php.

You see this PHP script doesn't work all the time, it cannot handle thousands of URLS. It sometimes works with hundreds or less, could you help improve this?

```
 <?php
error_reporting(0);
$error_404 = "Not Found";
$list_404 = array();
$sites = file('sites.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

foreach($sites as $site)
{
        $response = get_headers($site);
        if (strpos($response[0], $error_404))
        {
                $list_404[]=$site."
";
        }
}

file_put_contents('404.txt',$list_404);
?>
```

Comment: for one thing, this doesn't help you `error_reporting(0);` this does `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` should there be errors.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this to see where you are going wrong:

```
<?php

// Display Errors
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);

// Open File
$siteFile = fopen("sites.txt", "r");
// Create Array to Store 404 Error Sites
$errorList = array();

// Reading the File Line by Line
while(!feof($siteFile)){
    // Get the Site
    $site = (string)trim(fgets($siteFile));
    // Get the Headers
    $headers = get_headers($site);
    // Parse the Status Code from the Header
    $status = substr($headers[0], 9, 3);
    // If the Status Code is a 404, Push it into the Array
    if(intval($status) == 404){
        array_push($errorList, $site);
        echo "<li><b>{$site} {$headers[0]}</b></li>";
    }
    // Output the Status Code (Just so you can See it)
    else {
        echo "<li>{$site} {$headers[0]}</li>";
    }
}

// Do File Writing Here

// Close the Sites File
fclose($siteFile);
```

At least this way you'll be able to see the errors as well as the status for the sites in your list. Also, be sure that all of the URLs in your sites file are formatted with the HTTP

sites.txt:

```
http://www.google.com
http://www.facebook.com
http://www.gmail.com
http://hotdot.pro/en/404/
```

HTML Output:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
HTTP/1.0 301 Moved Permanently
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

Comment: I want the Url next to the HTTP/1.0 how do I do that?

Comment: Added that change to my solution.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the previous script by adding this "ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);"

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
$error_404 = "Not Found";
$list_404 = array();
$sites = file('sites.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

foreach($sites as $site)
{
        $response = get_headers($site);
        ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
        if (strpos($response[0], $error_404))
        {
                $list_404[]=$site."
";
        }
}

file_put_contents('404.txt',$list_404);
?>
```